# presto sql - sum up a column of int stored as varchar with empties

Tags: sql, presto, trino

i need to find the sum of a column but the numbers in it are stored as varchar and sum doesnt work with varchar

i cant cast them to in since cast function fails if it encounters empty strings

i tried replacing the empty strings with null and then coalescing with 0 but coalesce cant work on operands of different type

`sum(coalesce(nullif(c1,''),0)) as c`

what now?

Comment: So use a cast after the nullif.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex in your WHERE clause to check if the varchar is a valid number.

If you want to only match integers:

```
WHERE regexp_like(column, '\\d+')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`try_cast`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#try_cast):

```
sum(coalesce(try_cast(c1 as int), 0)) as c
```

Or if you want to handle only this specific failure you can use `if`:

```
sum(cast(if(c1 = '', '0', c1) as int)) as c
```